# Does git ignore capitalization changes in file names?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have branch A and branch B.

On branch A, I have a package with the name `xyz` and I change the package name to `xYz`. Next, I commit all of my changes and then switch to branch B. Now, once I switch to branch A, the package that I changed still has the value of `xyz` which is NOT what I committed. This happens in numerous cases.

The question: Does git ignore capitalization changes in file names or is this an issue on my part? I am using the SourceTree client if that helps.

Comment: Git does not, but Windows does. so if you're using Windows, that's why

Comment: What `git config.ignorecase` returns? If it is set to true, you could set it to false and try again your checkout.

Comment: @NevikRehnel, I am using a mac and it is being ignored.

Comment: @VonC, I am getting the following result when attempting what you suggested: `git: 'config.ignorecase' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @tambykojak sorry, I meant `git config core.ignorecase`

Comment: Awesome! It returned true, so I just set it to false. You typed in the comments so I don't know how to "accept" this question. I'm new to SO.

Comment: I have added an answer, but test it first

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to set (as mentioned in the question "[Git on windows: Can't switch branch after renaming a file (only changed case)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486721/6309)"):

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

And see if the issue persists.

Comment: I ran this command committed my files and now I have two copies of everything in the repository and my local copy thinks its up to date. What a weird config setting.

Comment: @NathanLunde-Berry What version of Git  are you using, on which OS?

Comment: @Nat do you reproduce the issue in a new clone of the same repo?

Comment: the repo looked fine it just had doubles. The old filenames and the new filenames, once I changed that setting. I resolved the issue by creating a new branch from within detached head mode and then switching back to master.

Comment: And then committing file deletions.

Comment: @NathanLunde-Berry OK. Never see that one before.

Answer (score 0):

It does ignore on mac too. Move the file somewhere else, add to index and than commit. After that get the file back and commit. Capitalisation schould be fixed.