# How to fix a git tracked file that is treated as untracked?

Tags: linux, windows, git, virtualbox

### Symptoms

I have a strange issue where I want to checkout a different branch `<branch2>`, but when I try I get the message that

```
$ git checkout <branch2>
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    <filename.xlsx>
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

However `git ls-files` lists `<filename.xlsx>` as a tracked file.

### Workaround

If I do a `git checkout -f <branch2>` it works, and the `<branch2>` version of the excel file is present and correct (similarly if I `rm <filename.xlsx>` and then checkout I get the correct file.)

To move back to `<branch1>` I get the exact same issue (`<filename.xlsx>` is tracked, but for checkout appears to be untracked).

### Testing/Troubleshooting

Investigating further this seems to be related to a Windows/Linux issue:

- I work predominantly in a VirtualBox VM of Debian, so I use my git tooling and terminal there, and access via a VirtualBox shared folder.
- Some of my code (this repository included) lives on the host system (Windows 10) as it is platform specific.
- If I use Git for Windows this issue does not occur.
- If I clone to a linux filesystem this issue does not occur.
- If I clone from upstream to a different Windows folder and access from linux I get the same issue.
- Other branches in the same repository that have the same file with different contents again **do not** suffer from the same issue (ie checkouts work as expected)
- Other commits with the same version of the file have the same issue.
- A small repo with just these two file versions does not exhibit the same behaviour, so, unfortunately, no easy way to create MCVE.

### Final Thoughts

Honestly, it is something that is relatively easy to work around, and seems limited in scope so far to only these two copies of the , but it has me intrigued. If anyone with greater knowledge of git has any ideas on how to diagnose/fix the root cause of this issue I would be very grateful.

### Extra debugging

Here is the results of `git ls-files --debug` from `<branch1>`

```
CodeSheet.xlsx
  ctime: 1489465633:751038200
  mtime: 1489465633:751038200
  dev: 38   ino: 5432
  uid: 0    gid: 999
  size: 14752   flags: 0
```

Here is the results of `git ls-files --debug` from `<branch2>`

```
Codesheet.xlsx
  ctime: 1489467487:720851100
  mtime: 1489467487:720851100
  dev: 38   ino: 5502
  uid: 0    gid: 999
  size: 12546   flags: 0
```

Comment: That *is* puzzling, because "untracked" literally means "not in the index". I'd suggest using `git ls-files --debug` to examine things more closely, and also check for "invisible" file name characters (white space, non-printing control characters, and the like).

Comment: @torek Had a look there and the main thing that is popping out is a case change between the two branches (which I hadn't noticed earlier). This is obviously the cause. Thanks heaps. at least I can "fix" it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess: this could be a [case of a file with a different case but the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15493135/6309).
From the case-insensitive Windows OS perspective, it is tracked, but from a case-sensitive Debian OS perspective, it is *not* tracked.

Try:

```
 git config core.ignorecase true
```

The [OP Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1468125/gavin) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777726/how-to-fix-a-git-tracked-file-that-is-treated-as-untracked/42778545?noredirect=1#comment72687570_42778545) using "[Changing capitalization of filenames in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)", with the [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) command.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did figure out in the end that it was indeed a case issue. I should have clicked that this was a possible reason for the issue as I think I even glanced at that question when I was searching. I've solved this specific instance of the issue in a different way by using your answer on [git mv](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/1468125).

Comment: @Gavin Great. I have include `git mv` in the answer for more visibility.